# Browser in CentOS 7 VPS

Tags: linux, google-chrome, firefox, browser, centos

I'm trying to run browser (Chrome, firefox) in my Centos 7 vps.

`google-chrome` command:

```
ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
```

`google-chrome --no-sandbox`:

```
[0618/195339.976436:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(308)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly
```

From a different user:

```
[chromer@vps123~]$ google-chrome --disable-setuid-sandbox
[26580:26580:0618/195404.014507:FATAL:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(116)] No usable sandbox! Update your kernel or see https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux/suid_sandbox_development.md for more information on developing with the SUID sandbox. If you want to live dangerously and need an immediate workaround, you can try using --no-sandbox.
Trace/breakpoint trap
[chromer@vps123~]$
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Is there a window manager installed on the VPS?

Comment: I don't think so. @music2myear

Comment: Does Chrome require such a window manager?

Comment: @music2myear I have no idea what is it, I'm just trying to run a browser on a CENTOS based VPS.

Comment: So, you've got a CLI only system and you're trying to run a GUI only program on it. There are text browsers that work in CLI systems. I think you need to do more research.

Comment: I want chrome/firefox, not cli browsers. my goal is to install one of those browser and use the graphical user interface just like windows